# Query entity elements by createdAt on specific date range does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My entity has createdAt field which is filled by `@CreatedDate` when the entity is created. This property is of `Date` type.

```
class MyEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

I would like to filter out all entities in a `List` that are in a range from startDate to endDate. The problem is that when I used `findAllByCreatedAtBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);` it worked but not for all cases. When the entity is created i.e.: 2019-10-25 14:15:23 I would like to get it also when the user will type as `@RequestParam` startDate from 2019-10-24 00:00 endDate to 2019-10-25 14:15 and also take this entity. How could I ignore everything that is behind minutes? Is there a way, because when I pass those values as startDate and endDate the entity isn't found, to find it I have to change 14:15 to 14:16.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any parameter without others in LocalDateTime. For example you want handle without minute. You can set your search date parameter like this:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime= myDate.atTime(14,15);//The first parameter is for Hour and other one is for minute.
```

You can find more detail here: [Java Time LocalDateTime At Time Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javatime/javatime_localdate_attime2.htm)